# Create lines in excel and group them

Tags: excel, vb.net

I am trying to create lines in excel and then group them using code below

```
Dim midobj As New List(Of Object)
Dim finobj As New Object()
for i as integer = 1 to 100
  Dim line1 = sht.Shapes.AddLine(i,10,i,100)
  midobj.Add(line1)
  Dim line2 = sht.Shapes.AddLine(i,10,i,100)
  midobj.Add(line2)
Next
finobj = midobj.ToArray
sht.Shapes.Range(finobj).Group()
```

I am getting the following error
"The index into the specified collection is out of bounds". Why and how to resolve this error

Comment: What happens if you use `i + 1` for `endX`?

Comment: I am drawing a straight vertical line, not a tilted one :)

Comment: See [Shapes.AddLine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.shapes.addline), `AddLine (BeginX, BeginY, EndX, EndY)` where **BeginX**: _The position (in [points](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/glossary/vbe-glossary#point)) of the line's starting point relative to the upper-left corner of the document._ **EndX**: _The position (in [points](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/glossary/vbe-glossary#point)) of the line's end point relative to the upper-left corner of the document._